# Displaying properties in Django admin - translating their names

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

In my Django application my model has some values set as properties - they are calculated on demand from other values (like, min. value of some other objects' field, etc). This works pretty well as I don't need to store those in the database and the calculations can be expensive, so they're cached.

So I have a model:

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(_('Name'))

    def max_of_some_values(self):
        # calculate it here, with caching,etc
        return 1
    max_value = property(max_of_some_values)
```

When I show this in my admin application, on the object list the `name` column is displaying using it's translation. So in Polish it's `Nazwa`, English it's `Name`, etc.

At the same time I found no way of adding a translated 'column' name for my property.

Anyone handled this before?

Answer (score 5):

You can set a `short_description` property on the method to determine the column name - I believe it should be possible to mark this as translatable.

```
def max_of_some_values(self):
    # calculate it here, with caching,etc
    return 1
max_of_some_values.short_description = _('Max value')
```

Comment: Almost there. For the Model you'll need to use `max_of_some_values.fget.short_description = _('Max value')`. Note the `fget` there. Otherwise you'll get a `short_description not defined` -error.